# forEach() to put() attachments throws conflict

Tags: pouchdb

Using an input of multiple images (creates array named storedFiles). The code below loads the first image into PouchDb and subsequently to CouchDB. But then it throws a 409 conflict error. Normally, I would have thought this was do to not capturing the rev of the first file. But the console.log("loop response rev" + response.rev) would seem to show that it is grabbing the 2nd rev.

Any tips on resolving this?

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3kz4NYLjRlIu4M6c2hcg

```
    local.put(mileageDoc, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      } else {
          storedFiles.forEach(function(storedFile){
                  console.log("response rev:" + response.rev);
            local.putAttachment(response.id, storedFile.name, response.rev, storedFile, storedFile.type, 
              function(err, response){
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log("Document created Successfully");
                  console.log("loop response id:" + response.id);
                  console.log("loop response rev:" + response.rev);
                  console.log("storedFiles length:" + storedFiles.length);
                }
              })
          })
      }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB [Upsert plugin](https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert) takes care of 409 conflicts:

> upsert() - update a document, or insert a new one if it doesn't exist
>   ("upsert"). Will keep retrying (forever) if it gets 409 conflicts.

Comment: But without dealing correctly with the rev of the original doc the images will all be uploaded in new doc's with upsert, correct? If so, this doesn't solve the problem as the images should all be part of the original doc.

Comment: @cgeiser With `upsert(docID, diffFun)` you don't need to be worried about revisions, you only pass document ID as an argument